# Live search and pagination not filtering results

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I am using a live search and a pagination, however, when I am doing the search, the render pagination still show other data not related to the search word I entered.

here is my input

```html
<input type="text"  id="search" placeholder="Search Patient" wire:model="search" class="searchbar"/>
```

here is my render

```php
public function render()
{
    $search = $this->search;
    $get_Country = DB::table('countries');
    $get_Country = $get_Country->select('country');

    $gender = DB::table('u_hispatients')->select('U_GENDER')->groupBy('U_GENDER')->get();
    $nationalities = DB::table('nationalities')->select('Nationality')->get();
    $get_Country=$get_Country->groupBy('country')->get();

    return view('livewire.u-hispatients',[ 
        'patients' => u_hispatient::Where('U_FIRSTNAME', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
                                ->orWhere('U_LASTNAME', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
                                ->orWhere('U_MIDDLENAME', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
                                ->orderBy($this->sortColumnName, $this->sortDirection)
                                ->paginate($this->perPage),
        'get_Country' => $get_Country,
        'gender' => $gender,
        'nationalities' => $nationalities]
    );
}
```

here is the blade file

```html
<div class="col search-cat float-right">
    <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search Patient" wire:model="search" class="searchbar" />
    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#studentModal"> Add Patient</button>
</div>

<div class="col">
    <label for="itemPerPage">Patients per Page:</label>
    <select name="itemPerPage" id=""wire:model="perPage" class="form-control">
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
    </select>

</div>
{{-- {{($search)}} --}}
<table class="mt-3 patient-list-table" id="patients">
    <thead>
        <th scope="col" class="table-code">
            <span class="float-left text-sm" wire:click="sortBy('CODE')"> Patient ID
                <i class="fa fa-arrow-up {{ $sortColumnName === 'CODE' && $sortDirection === 'asc' ? '' : 'hidden ' }} float-right pt-1"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-arrow-down {{ $sortColumnName === 'CODE' && $sortDirection === 'desc' ? '' : 'hidden ' }} float-right pt-1"></i>

            </span>
        </th>
        <th class="table-name-lname">
            <span class="float-left text-sm " wire:click="sortBy('U_LASTNAME')"> Last Name
                <i class="fa fa-arrow-up {{ $sortColumnName === 'U_LASTNAME' && $sortDirection === 'asc' ? '' : 'hidden ' }} float-right pt-1"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-arrow-down {{ $sortColumnName === 'U_LASTNAME' && $sortDirection === 'desc' ? '' : 'hidden ' }} float-right pt-1"></i>
            </span>
        </th>
        <th class="table-name-fname">
            <span class="float-left text-sm" wire:click="sortBy('U_FIRSTNAME')"> First Name
                <i class="fa fa-arrow-up {{ $sortColumnName === 'U_FIRSTNAME' && $sortDirection === 'asc' ? '' : 'hidden ' }} float-right pt-1"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-arrow-down {{ $sortColumnName === 'U_FIRSTNAME' && $sortDirection === 'desc' ? '' : 'hidden ' }} float-right pt-1"></i>
            </span>
        </th>
        <th class="table-name-mname">
            <span class="float-left text-sm" wire:click="sortBy('U_MIDDLENAME')"> Middle Name
                <i class="fa fa-arrow-up {{ $sortColumnName === 'U_MIDDLENAME' && $sortDirection === 'asc' ? '' : 'hidden ' }} float-right pt-1"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-arrow-down {{ $sortColumnName === 'U_MIDDLENAME' && $sortDirection === 'desc' ? '' : 'hidden ' }} float-right pt-1"></i>
            </span>
        </th>
        <th>Ext.</th>
        <th>Birth Date</th>
        <th>
            <span class="float-left text-sm table-name" wire:click="sortBy('U_GENDER')"> Sex
                <i
                    class="fa fa-arrow-up {{ $sortColumnName === 'U_GENDER' && $sortDirection === 'asc' ? '' : 'hidden ' }} float-right pt-1"></i>
                <i
                    class="fa fa-arrow-down {{ $sortColumnName === 'U_GENDER' && $sortDirection === 'desc' ? '' : 'hidden ' }} float-right pt-1"></i>
            </span>
        </th>
        <th>No. of Visit</th>
        <th>Status</th>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach ($patients as $item)
            <tr id="patientUpdate" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#viewPatientModal"
                wire:click="edit('{{ $item->CODE }}')">
                <td>{{ $item->CODE }}</td>
                <td>{{ $item->U_LASTNAME }}</td>
                <td>{{ $item->U_FIRSTNAME }}</td>
                <td>{{ $item->U_MIDDLENAME }}</td>
                <td>{{ $item->U_EXTNAME }}</td>
                <td>{{ $item->U_BIRTHDATE }}</td>
                <td>{{ $item->U_GENDER }}</td>
                <td>{{ $item->U_VISITCOUNT }}</td>
                <td>
                    @if ($item->U_ACTIVE == 1)
                        {{ 'Yes' }}
                    @else
                        {{ 'No' }}
                    @endif
                </td>
            </tr>
            {{-- @empty --}}
        @endforeach
        </td>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div class="pagination-content">
    {{ $patients->links('pagination::bootstrap-5-custom') }}
</div>
```

Comment: There's not enough information here, that pagination should work just fine. Can you show some examples of how it's not working?

Comment: If i search for a name "Jake" the pagination will display data that doesn't have the work jake.

Comment: Yeah, but there are 3 conditions that it searches for, so if it matches any of them. Just to be clear, you're talking about the data in `$patients` in the view, correct? What does the HTML look like?

Comment: Yes, it is the $patients, however, I already tried searching for only one field but still displays other results. I already updated my question and added the blade file, can you please, check if there is something wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Livewire has some rules which you need to follow. They are in the documentation, and what you're seeing here is a result of those conventions not being followed.

The exact thing you are seeing here, is a so-called "DOM-diffing issue". There are three elements here that I have changed,

1. The entire view must be encapsulated in one big `<div>`. There can only be ONE root element in that view.
2. The `<tr>` element in the `@foreach` loop has a `id` attribute which is not dynamic, meaning that it will create multiple IDs on the same page, which is bad (IDs must always be unique).
3. The `<tr>` element in your loop is generated dynamically, and therefor Livewire wants you to put `wire:key` on that, to something unique.

Note that I assume that your `$item` variable has an `id`, which is the unique identifier of that row in the database. If the primary key-field in the database is called something else, then change the `wire:key="patient-{{ $item->id }}"` to whichever is the unique of that row.

```html
<div>
    <div class="col search-cat float-right">
        <input type="text"  id="search" placeholder="Search Patient" wire:model="search" class="searchbar"/>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#studentModal"> Add Patient</button> 
    </div>

    <div class="col">
        <label for="itemPerPage">Patients per Page:</label>
        <select name="itemPerPage" id=""wire:model="perPage" class="form-control">
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="20">20</option>
            <option value="30">30</option>
        </select>

    </div>
    {{-- {{($search)}} --}}
    <table class="mt-3 patient-list-table" id="patients">
        <thead>
            <th scope="col" class="table-code">
                <span class="float-left text-sm" wire:click="sortBy('CODE')"> Patient ID
                    <i class="fa fa-arrow-up {{$sortColumnName ==='CODE' && $sortDirection ==='asc' ?'':'hidden '}} float-right pt-1"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-arrow-down {{$sortColumnName ==='CODE' && $sortDirection ==='desc' ?'':'hidden '}} float-right pt-1"></i>
                </span>
            </th>
            <th class="table-name-lname">
                <span class="float-left text-sm " wire:click="sortBy('U_LASTNAME')"> Last Name
                    <i class="fa fa-arrow-up {{$sortColumnName ==='U_LASTNAME' && $sortDirection ==='asc' ?'':'hidden '}} float-right pt-1"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-arrow-down {{$sortColumnName ==='U_LASTNAME' && $sortDirection ==='desc' ?'':'hidden '}} float-right pt-1"></i>
                </span>
            </th>
            <th class="table-name-fname">
                <span class="float-left text-sm" wire:click="sortBy('U_FIRSTNAME')"> First Name
                    <i class="fa fa-arrow-up {{$sortColumnName ==='U_FIRSTNAME' && $sortDirection ==='asc' ?'':'hidden '}} float-right pt-1"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-arrow-down {{$sortColumnName ==='U_FIRSTNAME' && $sortDirection ==='desc' ?'':'hidden '}} float-right pt-1"></i>
                </span>
            </th>
            <th  class="table-name-mname">
                <span class="float-left text-sm" wire:click="sortBy('U_MIDDLENAME')"> Middle Name
                    <i class="fa fa-arrow-up {{$sortColumnName ==='U_MIDDLENAME' && $sortDirection ==='asc' ?'':'hidden '}} float-right pt-1"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-arrow-down {{$sortColumnName ==='U_MIDDLENAME' && $sortDirection ==='desc' ?'':'hidden '}} float-right pt-1"></i>
                </span>
            </th>
            <th>Ext.</th>
            <th>Birth Date</th>
            <th>
                    <span class="float-left text-sm table-name" wire:click="sortBy('U_GENDER')"> Sex
                    <i class="fa fa-arrow-up {{$sortColumnName ==='U_GENDER' && $sortDirection ==='asc' ?'':'hidden '}} float-right pt-1"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-arrow-down {{$sortColumnName ==='U_GENDER' && $sortDirection ==='desc' ?'':'hidden '}} float-right pt-1"></i>
                </span>
            </th>
            <th>No. of Visit</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach($patients as $item)
                <tr wire:key="patient-{{ $item->id }}" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#viewPatientModal"  wire:click="edit('{{ $item->CODE }}')">
                    <td>{{ $item->CODE }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $item->U_LASTNAME }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $item->U_FIRSTNAME }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $item->U_MIDDLENAME }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $item->U_EXTNAME }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $item->U_BIRTHDATE }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $item->U_GENDER }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $item->U_VISITCOUNT }}</td>         
                    <td>
                        {{ $item->U_ACTIVE == 1 ? 'Yes' : 'No' }}
                    </td>
                @endforeach
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="pagination-content">
        {{ $patients->links('pagination::bootstrap-5-custom') }}
    </div>
</div>
```